# Open3d C++ Create File from point cloud failing due to unknown file extension

Tags: c++, c++20, ply, open3d

I'm attempting to read in a pointcloud .ply file using the open3d library in C++. When using either the `open3d::io::CreatePointCloudFromFile` or `open3d::io::ReadPointCloud(pcv_load_path, *pcv, open3d::io::ReadPointCloudOption(".ply", false, false, true))`

I'm using the newest version of the library, cxx 20, and cmake for linking the libraries.
Thank you.

I've tried running the same code in python and using the same path, that worked fine so I'm aware that the file isn't corrupt and the file format is correct. Here is the python code that I used:

```
pc_load = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(pcv_load_path)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pc_load])
```

I also have tried reading in the file in different way using the different IO function open3d offers. Here is the C++ code:

```
if (! open3d::io::ReadPointCloud (pcv_load_path, *pcv, open3d::io::ReadPointCloudOption ("auto", false, false, true))) {
    if (!open3d::io::ReadPointCloud(pcv_load_path, *pcv, open3d::io::ReadPointCloudOption(".ply", false, false, true))) {
            cout << "Error: cannot load point cloud" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
pcv = open3d::io::CreatePointCloudFromFile(pcv_load_path, ".ply", false);
```

*Note that pcv_load_path is the exact same in both. It is an explicit path and I'm using the forward slashes.

Also, in the pcv_load_path. I include ".ply" format to the end of the path string.

Edit:
Here is the output:

```
[Open3D WARNING] Read geometry::PointCloud failed: unknown file extension for  (format: ).
```

Edit:
I attempted to use the following code to output the file extension:

```
open3d::utility::filesystem::GetFileExtensionInLowerCase(pcv_load_path) << endl;
```

This results in a memory access violation and crashes the code.

Comment: Are you sure `".ply"` is a proper value for the `format` parameter ? Assuming your filename already contains the ".ply" extension, you can try to use "auto" for the `format` parameter (I am not familiar with open3d, just had a look at the documentation online).

Comment: Can you try calling open3d::utility::GetFileExtensionInLowerCase to see which extension is being returned. Should be ply. https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/ff22900c958d0216c85305ee8b3841e5699f9d57/cpp/open3d/utility/FileSystem.cpp#L87  or enable debug logging of open3d, see https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/ff22900c958d0216c85305ee8b3841e5699f9d57/cpp/open3d/io/PointCloudIO.cpp#L66

Comment: If ply is returned, you should be able to read pointcould using method ReadPointCloudFromPLY, see https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/ff22900c958d0216c85305ee8b3841e5699f9d57/cpp/open3d/io/PointCloudIO.cpp#L26

Comment: Unfortunately using the GetFileExtensionInLowerCase caused the program to crash.

Comment: @LiamSalass - This is no longer looking like an issue in `GetFileExtensionInLowerCase` code but some problem with open3d. However, just to be safe, can you copy whole code of method `GetFileExtensionInLowerCase` to a function of your own and test it with your variable `pcv_load_path`.  Code is here - https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/ff22900c958d0216c85305ee8b3841e5699f9d57/cpp/open3d/utility/FileSystem.cpp#L87

Comment: P.S. You need to tag me using @ symbol. Start typing first few characters of my username and autofill should work.